# How can I make my page refresh on form submit? - answered

Tags: php, forms, page-refresh

I'm coding a plugin with PHP and HTML, for a website I'm building - kind of a personalized goodreads for a local elementary school. In one page, my plugin displays a list of the user's favorite books, and a form to add a new book to the list. The problem is that if you fill out the form and click "submit," the SQL database does get modified immediately to reflect the new favorite book, but the list of favorite books doesn't update to show the new favorite book until you manually refresh the page. So for some reason, the page isn't automatically reloading every time the form gets submitted. But another plugin I made, which lists all the books someone has read, *does* update every time I submit the favorite books form (when I alter the favorite books plugin to update the all-books table instead of the favorite-books table). I've read the code for both lists several times, and I can't find any differences that would be significant between the list of favorite books and the list of all books.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

The favorite-books form and list are generated by one plugin, and the all-books form and list are generated by another. All are embedded in the web page via shortcode. The function to generate the favorite-books form is the following:

```php
function cr_top5_addbook_html() {
    echo '<form method="POST" action="/index.php/3669a-my-account/">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Add new favorite book <br>';
    echo 'Title: ';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cr-newbook" value="" size="40" /> <br> <br>';
    echo 'Author: ';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cr-newauthor" value="" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cr-top5-addbook-submitted" value="Add to Favorites"/></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

And the shortcode function for the favorites list is the following:

```php
function cr_top5_displaybooks_shortcode() { 
    ob_start();
    cr_top5_displaybooks_html();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, you should provide more info/code.

Comment: Can you provide more information of your code such as Where above function cr_top5_addbook_html is located ? And provide more detail in file index.php where action 3669a-my-account is defined

Comment: Also check Network tab, you probably get some error.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that your form processing / SQL insert happens AFTER your SQL select statement loading the favorite books list, and therefore the list isn't refreshed immediately after the form submission; instead, you're blurting out stale data. *If that's not the case, you need to show more code.*

Comment: Do you really need php to print html? What if you want to redesign layouts?

Comment: @MarkusAO you were right, thank you so much! I rearranged the elements on my page so that the form was above the display list, and that must have allowed it to load first; it's working fine now.

Comment: @Ebruell figured as much. It doesn't matter in what order you may echo/output things. What matters is the order of database operations. If you SELECT before you UPDATE, the data you'll have is, perhaps obviously, not yet updated. :)